# How to compress 4 consecutive blank lines into one single line in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl script to read a log so that to re-write the file into a new log by removing empty lines in case of seeing any consecutive blank lines of 4 or more.  In other words, I'll have to compress any 4 consecutive blank lines (or more lines) into one single line; but any case of 1, 2 or 3 lines in the file will have to remain the format.  I have tried to get the solution online but the only I can find is

```
perl -00 -pe ''
```

or

```
perl -00pe0
```

Also, I see the example in vim like this to delete blocks of 4 empty lines `:%s/^\n\{4}//` which match what I'm looking for but it was in vim not Perl.  Can anyone help in this?  Thanks.

Comment: Does "empty line" mean "only a single newline" or "nothing but whitespace characters"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To collapse 4+ consecutive Unix-style EOLs to a single newline:

```
$ perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's|\n{4,}|\n|g' file.txt
```

An alternative flavor using look-behind:

```
$ perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's|(?<=\n)\n{3,}||g' file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Zaid, I use your first command "perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's|\n{4,}|\n|' file.txt " and it was able to removed the empty spaces if the spaces happen in the middle of the text.  However the command is not able to get rid of the empty spaces that resides after the final line of text.  May I know how to resolve this?  I hav estill a few hundred empty lines after the final text.  Thanks.

Comment: @Grace : My guess is your "empty lines" are not empty at the end of the file, but contain whitespaces instead. You could confirm this by toggling special chars in a text editor.

Comment: No, it's because the regex doesn't have the `/g` switch which enables multiple substitutions. Without `/g` (or `|g` in this case), only the first match is replaced.

Comment: Thanks both of you Zaid and Memowe.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cnt = 0;

sub flush_ws {
  $cnt = 1 if ($cnt >= 4);
  while ($cnt > 0) {print "\n"; $cnt--; }
}

while (<>) {
  if (/^$/) {
    $cnt++;
  } else {
    flush_ws();
    print $_;
  }
}
flush_ws();
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't account for empty lines at the end of the input file properly.

Comment: Hi Perreal, Moritz Bunkus and TLP, thank a lot for your help but I finally get my question answers base on the simplest answer that I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-0` hint is a good one since you can use `-0777` to slurp the whole file in `-p` mode. Read more about these guys in [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) So this oneliner should do the trick:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{5,}/\n\n/g'
```

If there are up to four new lines in a row, nothing happens. Five newlines or more (four empty lines or more) are replaced by two newlines (one empty line). Note the `/g` switch here to replace not only the first match.

Deparsed code:

```
BEGIN { $/ = undef; $\ = undef; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\n{5,}/\n\n/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

HTH! :)

Comment: @Zaid was faster. Sorry for the duplicate. Our solutions use different `\n` counts - I interpreted the question this way, but changing the regex is an easy exercise for @Grace. ;)

Comment: Hi Memowe, Thanks for your sugestion and I'm using the first command that you suggest (same as Zaid) in the line.  May I know what is the -pe and  means as the command line used by Zaid just having -e.  As I replied to Zaid, the command actually works fine to eliminate empty spaces in between lines of text but not if the empty spaces happen after the final line of text.  Do you have idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Grace: please consult [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) for a complete `-p` explanation. It enables the while loop with a final `print` and @Zaid has it in his solution too, in `-pi.bak`. The `-i.bak` is for in-place substitution with a backup copy with a `.bak` file name extension. I just checked and I'm pretty sure my version substitutes empty lines on the end of the file because it uses `/g`.

Comment: Thanks Memowe, I finally combined Zaid and your solution to get my thing done. It somehow fail to get the result if I just use the -pe without the -i.bak option (perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{5,}/\n\n/g' file.txt). I finally get it done by this command:-perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's/\n{4,}/\n\n/g file.txt

Comment: Without -i the output goes to STDOUT, you can capture it with `$ perl ... > new_file`. HTH.

Comment: No votes for my answer feels a little bit strange since I even helped to improve Zaids solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`, setting the record separator to NUL:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\0" } { gsub(/\n{5,}/,"\n")}1' file.txt
```

This assumes that you're definition of empty excludes whitespace

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need

```
perl -ne 'if (/\S/) {$n = 1 if $n >= 4; print "\n" x $n, $_; $n = 0} else {$n++}' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin for your help.